# Thinking math critically

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, soft-question

First, I'm from Indonesia and trying to take SBMPTN (kindal GRE or SAT test)

I have trouble in math. Which my teacher says that math is about creativity. But here's the main question

How do I improve the creativity? Such as working on some difficult calculus problem. Some genius figured their way out with astonishing method. I'm wondering, how do they do that...

Need enlightenment...

Comment: Very few people are geniuses. Most people work hard for understanding. I recommend you work as many problems as you can before your test, that is, similar problems to those which will be on the test.

Comment: It took a genius to figure out calculus originally, but since then people have found ways to explain calculus that make it seem much less difficult.  At this level I would say that calculus requires "understanding" more than "creativity". Be sure to focus on understanding rather than rote memorization or blindly following rules.

Comment: Do as many of  the unsolved exercises in your book as you can. After you have done 10,000 of them reevaluate yourself.

Comment: what trouble you have made your teacher said this? There should be some context.

Answer (score 3):

Talent is innate. But you are not expected to be a genius; you are expected to understand notions and methods that have been studied and analyzed a lot, and that many people understand very well.

In the end, you cannot buy nor make up talent. But you can study and, over all, practice, practice, practice. Besides a real life prof/tutor/TA, this site is a great resource for asking clarification when you don't understand what you are studying.

Answer (score 0):

"A skill is something you learn. Talent is what you can't help doing". Well, not everyone is a genius, but it doesn't mean that they are always good at everything. Practice more would really help you perform better. There are so many online sources and open data out there. Try to understand the proofs of some hard math problems, or the way teachers create those sorts of questions. By the way, always be confident. Hope those "tips" would help. Hope you have a good grade. ;)